# Questions about JSON.stringify in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-5, stringify

I'm watching [MDN's "Using native JSON"](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON). And I've 3 questions about the `JSON.stringify` method.

**Question 1:**

```
var foo = {
    "foundation": "Mozilla",
    "model": "box",
    "week": 45,
    "transport": "car",
    "month": 7
},
    censor = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            return;
        }
        return value;
    };
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, censor)); // String: {"week":45,"month":7}
```

Codes above work fine. But why can't codes below work fine?

```
var foo = {
    "foundation": "Mozilla",
    "model": "box",
    "week": 45,
    "transport": "car",
    "month": 7
},
    censor = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'string') {
            return;
        }
        return value;
    };
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, censor)); // undefined
```

**Question 2:**

Please observe codes below:

```
var foo = {
    "foundation": "Mozilla",
    "model": "box",
    "week": 45,
    "transport": "car",
    "month": 7
},
    censor = function (key, value) {
        return 2;
    };
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo, censor)); // String: 2
```

I think my codes should get string below because "If you return a Number, the string corresponding to that number is used as the value for the property when added to the JSON string." (quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON).

```
{"foundation":2,"model":2,"week":2,"transport":2,"month":2}
```

But I just get a string `2`. Why?

**Question 3:**

If I wanna get `{"foundation":2,"model":2,"week":2,"transport":2,"month":2}`, how should I change the codes?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `foo` is an object (`{…}`). Objects are not strings. You censor the outer object, so it never gets recursed into.
2. Because you return `2` for `foo` instead of recursing into it
3. Test if it is a string or a number (instead of testing if it isn't a string) then return 2